# Running a duplicate Java Project on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I'm working on Java project for a portal. I checked out a sample portal from an svn, and pasted a renamed copy of it in the eclipse package explorer.

When I tried to run this new project on a Tomcat 7 server, I got the error message:

> Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.
>   Multiple Contexts have a path of "/SamplePortal".

What do I need to do to get this new project to run?

Comment: change the context in web.xml file

Comment: Don't know if it is the same on Tomcat, but on JBoss we had a lot of problems with two classes having the same package and same classname. You should always change the package name when deploying on the same server. Also change web.xml as others pointed out.

Comment: Indeed, changing the context will allow you to run a copy of your application. However, **make sure that you make any static variable/resource final or you will run into some nasty side effects**.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: how do you 'change the package name'? What package name are you specifically referring to?

Comment: I went into the web.xml file under the web-inf folder and the only specification for context had the information   <context-param>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

Comment: @okiharaherbst all the package names of duplicated classes. If you recompile some classes with same packages and same names, you could have ClassCastExceptions at runtime if the class loader is the same.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: What do you mean by 'recompile'? You are just deploying a webapp (we're talking about Tomcat, aren't we?). Perhaps I misunderstood the thread, I thought that the OP had a webapp and wanted to run two instances of it on the same Tomcat server. If the OP intended to copy–paste the project, I'd highly suggest recycling what can be under a single jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the suggestions in this thread are valid. If you extract the war file into a folder inside of Tomcat's webapps folder, it should work.

If you are trying to do it from Eclipse, make sure the file server.xml is not corrupted, or that Eclipse is not misreading it. Restart Eclipse if that is the case.

Comment: I went into the server.xml file and found that both the sample and new project were mapped to the same path. I changed it and new my project is up and running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your project directory or .war file so it doesn't conflict with the existing SamplePortal project.

Comment: I renamed the project directory for the duplicate project before the error. Something else is causing the error.